# How to set a color as a global variable in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to set predefined colors in PowerApps using the function `Set`, however, when I check the variables tab the variable does not have a value (NA).

The syntax on the option **OnStart** I am using is as follows:

`Set(LightOrange, ColorValue("#ee7f00"))`

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: when you go on your screen, in advanced you will see Fill, you can change the color there, it is in RGBA format like RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1)

Comment: The idea is declare the color as a variable, so you only write down the name of the color and avoid writing that code every time, or selecting it from the palet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong in what you're doing. You cannot see that `LightOrange` variable value what you're setting in `OnStart` under `Variables` area like debug mode.

I'm seeing `arunColor` variable with `No value`.
[image]

I'm assigning `#0000ff` (Blue) using `Set` from App `OnStart`
[image]

I'm assigning that variable value `arunColor` as control color `Fill`
[image]

I'll use one of these urls to access the App after save & publish.

```
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/d68b7936-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ce064e3f1637
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/d68b7936-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ce064e3f1637?tenantId=e485c427-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-add2e5942a49
```

Voila! I see the control color changed.
[image]

**Reason**:
`OnStart` is designed to trigger when the app is opened very first time. If you make changes in color, then you have to open the App again to see the changes.